# Trading strategy with only knowledge of price increase/decrease?

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, trading, algorithmic-trading

Take a hypothetical model that takes a stock as input and outputs "up" or "down" indicating if the stock price will increase or decrease in a fixed time interval T.

Assuming the model is correct >50% of the time, what are the strategies to trade given this information? No indication of how much the stock increases/decreases so a simple buy strategy would obviously fail.

Comment: Input several stock names until you get a stock that is predicted to go up and one which is predicted to go down. Then buy the first and short the second.

Comment: @nbbo2 But the distribution of increase/decrease signals by the model may not be uniform across all stock prices.

Comment: @nbbo2 In other words it may be biased such that its more likely to output increase for low % increase stocks, and more likely to output decrease for high % decreasing stocks

Comment: nbbo2, is still right I believe. (e.g if you short a portfolio of stocks that goes down by 10%, and you take a long position in a portfolio of stocks that go up by 2%. You make profit on both positions as long as there are low transaction costs. However, you should be aware that past performance does not guarantee future performance and the models predictive power may change over time (as for instance market conditions, regulation and events change).

Comment: In addition, ideally you'd still want to have an indication of volatility and other underlying risk factors, as well as the magnitude of returns. Since this can give you an idea of the risk you are taking and the relative compensation for these risks. Even if you predict the direction correctly in 51% of the cases, if the negative return from the 49% of wrongly predicted cases outweighs the positive return from the correctly predicted cases, you'd still lose money. Hence the magnitude still matters.

Comment: @JulienMaas Yeah that's my point of the question. If a model doesn't give any magnitude, then buy/sell strategies won't work.

Comment: @nbbo2 If the stock I bought/(shorted) goes down/(up) 100% with 49% chance and up/down 1% with 51% chance then I lose.

Comment: @BeefJerky: you need predicted up and down returns or probabilities of up and down. You can't do anything with what you have.

Comment: @markleeds I am unable to come up with a strategy right now, but I don't believe that it's impossible. Do you have a math proof? The model gives information. There should be a strategy for any type of information

Comment: BeefJerky:  I'm not tryng to be difficult or mean and your question is interesting. But my take is that there is information but it's not enough. For example, you don't know if the expected return on the ups even cover transaction cost.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it matters what probabilities are priced into the market. Assuming the market prices a 50/50 percent of up/down at time T, then you could trade a call or put spread to bet on the probability of stock going up or down.

If the stock is fair at 100, and the model says it will go up you could buy a European 100-d/100+d call spread expiring at time T. If d is small enough, this is essentially a bet on probability of stock being above or below 100 at time T.